# Cloning windows 7 fails

Tags: windows

I am using aronis true image 2014 premium to clone a drive. the drive booted up just fine after a clone in the same machine but when I switch the new SSD drive over to the new system WIndows will not boot up.

What do I need to do?

error: 0xc000000e
the boot selection failed because a required device is inacessable.

Comment: Didn't you get any error messages? What exactly happened?

Comment: did you clone the system partition too? System partition is 100 MB in size

Comment: Is the hardware alike? Otherwise a clone means you are still using all the wrong drivers... Regardless, more info required. Otherwise all we can do is guess what errors you are having

Comment: nope. the drive is going into new hardware. and yes. i clonded the entire drive and it boots fine in the old machine but not the new one. ill update with the boot error

Comment: Also check that your BIOS is referencing the correct drive. I've seen the occasional issue where the BIOS is trying to boot off a non-bootable drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build reference images in VMs. I promise you, once you stop building reference images on physical hardware, 99% of all your problems go away. Did you even bother to sysprep this system?

Comment: what is sysprep? and reference images?

Comment: @MDTGuy You need to write blog posts for Superuser on this topic... Before I cry...